# Issue with printing char pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am calling a function of return type struct Function, as specified below:

```
typedef enum {string,integer} ReturnType;
typedef struct Function{
    ReturnType returnType;
    char *token;
    char *tokenProgress;
    char *result;
    void (*init)(struct Function *self);
} Function;
void Function_init(Function *self, ReturnType returnType,char *token, char *tokenProgress){
    self->returnType = returnType;
    self->token = token;
    self->tokenProgress = tokenProgress;
    self->result = "";
}
```

In the main loop of my program I want to print the result pointer contained within the struct, like so:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    while(true){
        scanf("%s",command);
        Function *func = executeCommand(command);
        printf("%s\n", func->result);
    }
}
```

Here is executeCommand:

```
Function * executeCommand(char command[]){
    Function *currentFunction;
    char *token;
    char *tokenProgress;
    Function_init(currentFunction,integer,token,tokenProgress);
    char result[11];
    sprintf(result,"%d",3);
    currentFunction->result = result;
    return currentFunction;
}
```

However, when I run the program, only a newline character is printed when it should print "3\n". I have run the program using gdb to check that `func->result` has a value:

```
(gdb) print func->result
(char *) $0 = 0x00007fff5fbffa9d "3"
```

I checked this value at a breakpoint placed on the line printing `func->result`, so I am at a loss as to why it is not printing since it clearly has a value and the struct is being returned correctly.

Comment: Do you place the character `'3'` into the result buffer, or the integer value `3`?

Comment: How is `executeCommand` implemented?

Comment: What is `command`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I don't see any `malloc`/`calloc` here, where is the struct allocated?

Comment: Where do you call `Function_init()` and what parameters do you pass?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Also please include the input you give to the program. And while in the debugger do try to step through the code line by line to see that it does what you expect it to do.

Comment: command is a char pointer, executeCommand is several 100 lines long so for the purposes of this question I'm going to write a basic function to take its' place

Comment: Is `executeCommand` returning a pointer to a local variable? This is a very common mistake.

Comment: You *do* make the pointers you have actually *point* somewhere? Somewhere that doesn't go out of scope (like the variable `result` in your example of the `executeCOmmand` function)?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Why do you care about his code? `printf("%s\n", func->result);` is largely enough knowing that `func->result` is a `char *`. If the printf does not print anything it can only mean that a NULL character is encountered before any printable character, either because it points to garbage or because it holds wide characters. A good thing would be to know what are the values of `func->result[i]`.

Comment: @BenjaminT - We care about his code exactly because it's his code that produces undefined behavior by accessing a buffer that went out of scope. It's pointless to discuss what's at `func->result[i]` since merely accessing it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yeah, my bad... I had faith because gdb printed "3"

Comment: Another thing: in `executeCommand` you call `Function_init` with uninitialized parameters.

Comment: They are initialised in the actual function, it's just that there's a load of strtok_r usage that I'd have to add to initialise those variables to what they'd be in the actual program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `currentFunction->result = result` in `executeCommand`, which lets your structure's `result`-member point to local variable `result`. The storage of this local variable will be dismissed once `executeCommand` has finished, and your structure member will point to "invalid" memory.

To avoid the loss of the local variable when `executeCommand` completes, memory can be allocated within `executeCommand` (e.g. with `malloc` or `calloc` or `realloc`) to provide storage for `result` which will survive after `executeCommand` has returned.

Comment: Thanks, changing `char *result` to `char result[11]` and then using `strcpy(currentFunction->result, result)` sorted it for me

Comment: Nothing here is *sorted*. The code is full of Undefined Behaviour. You need to allocates memory for currentFunction. Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is going to create a mess.

Comment: The answer should be deleted. It introduces even more UB.

Comment: currentFunction is initialised using `Function_init(...)` in the 4th line of `executeCommand()`, as for your reference to undefined behaviours that's outside the scope of the original question

Comment: @BrianJaniston: `Function_init()` cannot initialize `currentFunction`, since C uses pass by value. Just like how `int x; Integer_init(x);` will leave `x` uninitialized.